# How to get the first value in the list

Tags: python

```
  obj = ['Execute', 'execute', 'VERB']

  if obj is not None:
        for token in obj :
            ....???
```

how to get the first element using Python?

Comment: In sets the order is undefined. If order is important, don't use a set, but a list.

Comment: ```set``` object is not subscriptable. That means, you cannot access items in a set by referring to an index like in a ```list``` or a key in a ```dict```.

Comment: You can convert the set to a list and get the first element `list(obj)[0]`.

Comment: @Jakob converting the whole set to a list only to get the first element... `next(iter(obj))` is a more efficient approach

Comment: @Jakob, you cannot do that. Because, with set there is no gurantee which item will be in which index while converting to a list.

Comment: @Marat I probably missunderstood the question, what does your code do?

Comment: [https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset)

Comment: @Jakob same thing as `list(obj)[0]`

Comment: @Jakob: The advantage to `next(iter(obj))` is that it's `O(1)`; no matter how many items are in `obj`, the cost to convert to an iterator and extract the first item is fixed. `list(obj)[0]` requires `O(n)` work, creating an N-element `list` even though you only use the first item in it.

Comment: @BhusalC_Bipin Ah, I see. So different values in `obj` could result in a wrong first value?

Comment: @ddejohn: `set`s are not insertion-ordered, they have arbitrary order (a given `set`'s iteration order is repeatable as long as it is unmodified, but building the same set in different ways, or in the same way but in different runs of the program, can produce different orderings). You're probably thinking of `dict`s, which are guaranteed insertion-ordered in Python 3.7+ (and ordered as an implementation detail in CPython 3.6).

Comment: @Jakob, even with the same values, if you run ```list(obj)[0]``` multiple times, you will get different items. As while converting a ```set``` to ```list```, there is no gurantee on which order the items will be stored in the ```list```.

Comment: @BhusalC_Bipin: If you run it multiple times without modifying `obj` in the same run of the program, you won't get different items each time. It only changes when `obj` is built in a different way, or in new runs of the program (thanks Python seeding the hashes of most things that can be interpreted as a stream of bytes in some way). The iteration order is arbitrary, but for an unmodified `set` within a given run of the program, it will be consistent.

Comment: Yeah I assumed sets got the same treatment as dicts in 3.6. TIL.

Comment: Thank you @ShadowRanger, point to be noted.

Comment: @ddejohn: Ah, gotcha. Yeah, the main advantages of insertion-ordered `dict`s didn't apply as frequently for `set`s, and the disadvantages involved with preserving order even in the face of keys being deleted were more apparent and likely to occur in typical `set` use cases, so they kept `set`s unchanged. `set`s started as a simple wrapper around `dict` way back in early 2.x days, but the implementations have diverged *dramatically* over time, largely in support of `dict`'s use for global-scope/class/instance namespaces and for passing and receiving arbitrary `**kwargs`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is "how to get the *first* element?". In this case, you are going to need a data structure that is both *ordered* and *indexible*. For purposes where you don't want the structure to be mutable, use a Python tuple. If you want mutability, use a list.
A few things:

1. A python set is "a collection which is unordered, unchangeable, and unindexed." (W3Schools) So in this case, you can't get the *first* element because, it isn't indexed that way.
2. Using a list, common indexing syntax is as follows:

```py
list = ['Execute', 'execute', 'VERB']
list[0] #will return 'Execute'
```

Answer (score 3):

In Python, you cannot index into a set - these data structures are unordered and unindexed.

If you really insist on having `obj` be a set, you could do something like the following:

```py
if "Execute" in obj:
  print("Execute")
```

However, this isn't really a great way to manage this problem. The code snippet in your question suggests you want a way to store your data that *is* indexable. I would suggest a list:

```py
obj = ['Execute', 'execute', 'VERB']  ## this is not a set
first_element = obj[0]
print(first_element) ## this will print 'Execute'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the first element in iteration order, whatever that happens to be, do:

```
first = next(iter(obj))
```

That'll raise `StopIteration` if `obj` is empty, otherwise it gets the first item you'd iterate over from `obj`. It's cheap at least; running in `O(1)` time, so even if `obj` has a million items in it, it will run quickly (where `list(obj)[0]` will take longer and longer for bigger and bigger `obj`).

To be clear, `set`s have arbitrary order; even if the first time you run this code it produces `'Execute'`, there's no guarantee a `set` with the same contents, constructed in a different order, or a `set` constructed the same way in a different run of the program, will iterate in the same order. `next(iter(obj))` is getting you an effectively *arbitrary* element, it has no meaning beyond being arbitrarily first in the iteration order for this `set`, built in this specific way, in this specific run of the program.